# Using functions defined in primitive modules

Tags: rust

I'd like to make use of this function:

[`u8::from_str(src: &str) -> Result<u8, ParseIntError>`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u8.html#method.from_str)

I can't seem to figure out the syntax to use it.  This is what I am currently trying

```
use std::u8;

match u8::from_str("89") {
    // Stuff...
}
```

I receive the following error:

```
error: unresolved name `u8::from_str`
```

What is the proper way to use functions that are defined in primitive modules?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick here is that `from_str` is actually part of the trait [`FromStr`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html). You need to use that trait, then specify which implementation you want to use:

```
use std::str::FromStr;

fn main() {
    match <u8 as FromStr>::from_str("89") {
        // Stuff...
    }
}
```

However, this particular concept has a more ergonomic option: [`parse`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.StrExt.html#tymethod.parse):

```
fn main() {
    match "89".parse::<u8>() {
        // Stuff...
    }
}
```

And you might be able to remove the `::<u8>` if something else constrains the type enough for it to be inferred.